# What should I do when I find incorrect/deficient tagging paterns?

Tags: discussion, tags

I sometimes notice patterns of incorrect tagging, or deficiency in tagging. For example, today I noticed a pattern of posts involving [fast-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fast-math) which did not include that tag.

Later, while reviewing and editing these posts I noticed another problematic pattern - of users tagging their questions with [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization) when (it seems) they should be using [compiler-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-optimization).

So,

- What should I do when I notice improper tagging patterns affecting a large number of posts?
  <sub><sup>(Other than reviewing the affected posts)</sup></sub>
- Are there any criteria I should adhere to with regards to editing?
- Are there any side effects to concentrated editing that I should know about?